# Using implicitlyWait with getElements is seriously slowing my test times

Tags: java, scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scalatest

We are working in legacy code and have a problem with flaky tests.

I'd like to increase the default timeout, but the driver.findElement is used in a lot of places - overriding each call to use WebDriverWait would be a big task.

I found a recommendation to use implicit waits, which looked ideal as it only needed to be set once:

```
getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I added this to the initialisation code block. Unfortunately, when I run one test case (50 tests) my performance bombs - increasing from ~30 seconds to 600 seconds.

I don't understand why the performace has got so much worse - I thought it would only have taken the maximum time if the elements weren't present (the tests passed).  I thought this call would poll for the  condition.  But I also can't see where to set the poll interval...  It does mention in the documentation that it should be used judiciously, but this is completely unusable!

Are we on the right track with using implicitlyWait()?  Is there another way to toughen up our tests?

UPDATE
On investigation, it appears that it is using implicitlyWait() and driver.getElements() that is slowing us down - if i nullify the implicitwait then reapply it straight after the call, then the tests run much faster.  We use getElements ins over 400 places (!) - any recommendations on how to proceed?

Comment: I strongly suspect there's more to the situation than the single line of code you've posted here would imply. In theory, you're right, that the implicit wait timeout should only wait the full timeout if the element is not found. It might be useful to see the actual code of the test case that has begun to perform poorly. It would also be useful to know if this happens in all browsers or just one, and if only one (or you're only running against one), which browser and version.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse.  We have started to have the same suspicions.  Unfortunately due to the sprawling nature of the legacy code, it is difficult to show useful representative code samples... we are hunting down the source of the problem now. It's good to know we are on the right path though - thanks!

Comment: Question updated with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We weren't able to track down why this was happening with implicitlyWait.  In the interests of making our build reliable, we wrote overrode getElement with our own polling mechanism, with a fairly low polling interval (100ms).

This has improved the accuracy of our tests, without affecting the build duration.

```
override def findElement(selector: By): WebElement = {
      val timeoutTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout
      def helper(): WebElement = {
        try {
          super.findElement(selector)
        } catch {
          case exception: NoSuchElementException => {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeoutTime) {
              throw exception
            } else {
              Thread.sleep(pollInterval)
              helper()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      helper()
    }
```